# Workaround On Edit script trigger for sheet changed by formula

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Complete beginner here in need of help.

**Background**: I wrote a script to pull IMPORTHTML content to a single cell of my Google Sheet. This is triggered to refresh every minute and works flawlessly. In a second script, I want to send a message to my Slack channel if the content of that cell changes. This code works flawlessly, as well.

**The problem**: The On Edit installable trigger on the "post to Slack" script does not fire. Because the cell's value changes by way of a formula and not a user's manual edit, no change is detected.

**The solution**: I'm hoping you can help me here! This issue (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113063/trigger-when-a-cell-value-changed-by-formula) seems almost identical to mine, and the solution seems plausible, but after reading Google's resources on Properties, I am even more confused.

Can anyone suggest some code that would store the cell's base value, check it every minute against the cell's current content, and--if change is detected--update the base value and proceed with the rest of my "post to Slack" code?

Comment: Why not just combine both the flawless script to a single script bypassing sheets(or just keeping it in loop)?

Comment: Wow, thanks for responding. I really appreciate that. When I wrote "beginner" I should clarify I am super ignorant. I'm sorry. What does it mean to bypass sheets or keep in loop? The only "coding" I've ever done is in Google Apps Scripts...

Comment: Get the data through your importhtml script, check whether the value retrieved is the same as in sheets,If so, run the Slack script, else close the importhtml script.

Comment: That sounds plausible. So I would keep the entire script on a minute timer, right? I'm struggling to understand how the value in the spreadsheet would be updated so that the next time the script runs, it would be checking the IMPORTHTML against the most updated value...and if those values don't match, it would run the Slack script and replace the old spreadsheet value with the new finding...

Comment: Thanks, I'-'I ! You helped me see it differently. I rewrote my code for a single script, set with installable Time trigger to run every minute. For future internet travelers, here's what I did:

Comment: `function getData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID"); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("NAME");
  var queryString = Math.random();
  var cell = sheet.getRange(2,1);

  var cellFunction = '=QUERY(IMPORTHTML("INSERT URL","list",9),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 CONTAINS \'added\' limit 1")';
    sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(cellFunction); 
  
  if(sheet.getRange(2,2).getDisplayValue() != sheet.getRange(2,1).getDisplayValue()) {      
    var cellUpdate = sheet.getRange(2,2).getDisplayValue();
    sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue(cellUpdate);
    postSlack();
  }
}
`

Comment: And then I had a postSlack function to determine the payload and a sendSlack function to deliver it.

Comment: Post an answer. Comments will be deleted.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of the rules. I did run into an issue though. The IMPORTHTML is no longer returning values, instead showing "N/A." I was led to believe that the number of calls it can make may be capped, and since I'm running it every minute to check for changes, I fear that's my problem. Is there any way to use UrlFetchApp to avoid IMPORTHTML altogether?

Comment: Yes. When you said IMPORTHTML script, I assumed you were using UrlFetch. Look into documentation... should be easy